# Disabling NextJS SSG - Hook vs Const

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I'm testing different ways to disable NextJS SSG.

The following hook works

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const useClientCheck = () => {
  const [isClient, isClientSet] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    isClientSet(true);
  }, []);
  return isClient;
};

export function LayerHook({ children }) {
  const isClient = useClientCheck();
  if (!isClient) return null;
  return (
    <>
      <h1>LayerHook</h1>
      {children}
    </>
  );
}
```

However, if I check a const like

```
const ISSERVER = typeof window === "undefined";

export function LayerConst({ children }) {
  if (ISSERVER) return null;
  return (
    <>
      <h1>LayerConst</h1>
      {children}
    </>
  );
}
```

It complains with message

> Expected server HTML to contain a matching `<h1>` in `<div>`

To me, the second option is equivalent to the first yet more efficient. Why is throwing an exception with second option but not the first?

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/next-js-hook-vs-const-n4eb7?file=/components/LayerConst.js:0-197

Comment: Pardon me for asking, but why use NextJS if you don't want to SSR? The `useEffect` doesn't run until after the initial render, which happens on the client side. I don't know if *that* is the difference though. I'm also not seeing the complaint message in your linked CSB.

Comment: @DrewReese Looks like I made a mistake. I want to disable SSG for particular pages like auth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're close but not equivalent. While it's true that `useEffect` only runs on the client, here's what you're saying in each:

##### First Example (with the hook)

When you (Next) build this component, give me a fragment with a h1 and render the children. (At this point of the build stage, Next isn't running React so it's going to build the html of the component.) When React is hydrated, run this component. I'm telling you that `isClient` is false, so return `null`. And then on the client, after `useEffect` runs, you'll see that `isClient` is `true` so go ahead and render my html for the user.

##### Second Example (using `typeof window`)

When you (Next) build this component, check if `window` is defined. If so, build this html. If not, "build" a null component. When React is hydrated, run this component. If we're on the client, you'll see that `window` is defined and the component should render my html for the user.

##### Why Next is/isn't complaining

Next isn't complaining about your first example because it's creating the html on the server inside your `return` when it builds the component, passes that to the client, and it matches when React hydrates on the client. It's "complaining" about your second example because it's not actually creating that html on the server, so when it sees it on the client after React hydrates - voila, the warning.

Keep in mind the differences between Next's *build* process and running `next dev`. If you want to disable SSR, no problem - just don't use `getInitialProps` or `getServerSideProps` anywhere. When you run `next build`, it will build everything as a static page and you won't have any SSR - it just won't exist. *But*, using your two examples - when Next builds this page, the first one will have the raw html (div, h1) in the source code while the second one will not.

Finally, keep in mind that you can't really disable SSR during `next dev`. If you *have* to have SSR and you're trying to disable it for a specific component, then you're going down a reasonable path here. But if you just want a static site, you don't need workarounds like this to disable SSR - it will be disabled when you build the site without `getInitialProps` or `getServerSideProps` (or a custom `document` or `app` component).

##### Update with sample built code

There's some discussion in the comments so I'm updating to include some *built* code to show what is actually compiled versus what React sees. For this, I created two page components in Next using the code from OP but just modified the `return` method to return a paragraph tag:

```
// pages/sample-hook.tsx
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"

const useClientCheck = () => {
  const [isClient, isClientSet] = useState(false)
  useEffect(() => {
    isClientSet(true)
  }, [])
  return isClient
}

export default function SamplePageWithHook() {
  const isClient = useClientCheck()
  if (!isClient) return null
  return <p>Sample Page</p>
}
```

```
// pages/sample-null.tsx
export default function SamplePageWithNull() {
  if (typeof window === "undefined") {
    return null
  }
  return <p>Sample Page</p>
}
```

If you look at the pages built by Next, here's what you'll get:

```
// .next/server/pages/sample-hook.js
const useClientCheck = ()=>{
    const { 0: isClient , 1: isClientSet  } = (0,react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.useState)(false);
    (0,react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.useEffect)(()=>{
        isClientSet(true);
    }, []);
    return isClient;
};
function SamplePageWithHook() {
    const isClient = useClientCheck();
    if (!isClient) return null;
    return(/*#__PURE__*/ react_jsx_runtime__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.jsx("p", {
        children: "Sample Page"
    }));
};
```

```
// .next/server/pages/sample-null.js
function SamplePageWithNull() {
    if (true) {
        return null;
    }
    return(/*#__PURE__*/ react_jsx_runtime__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.jsx("p", {
        children: "Sample Page"
    }));
};
```

In `sample-hook.js`, when React is hydrated, `useClientCheck` is interpreted and the component returns the html or `null` based on `useClientCheck`. Because of this hook, React is aware that this component can return *either* the html or `null`.

In `sample-null.js`, no matter what, React interprets this component and only sees that it can return null. The code after `is(true)` is never reached so that possible output never makes it into the React tree and React is never made aware of it.

This is why the warning is generated in the second scenario and why the first and second are not the equivalent. The warning is telling you that React is rendering something in `sample-null.js` that it previously didn't know about and wasn't previously in the tree.

Comment: "*Next isn't complaining about your first example because it's creating the html on the server inside your `return`*" - no? That `return` statement is never executed on the server, as `isClient` is `false`, and the html is never built. It builds a `null` component.

Comment: @Bergi the html is still being built on the server in the first example because the React hook isn't run until React itself is run. On the server, React is built using `renderToString` which means the hook in the first example is not executed during the initial html rendering on the server, and will only render what's in the `return` method. Once React is hydrated, the hook is called but at this point the html has already been built. In the second example, node understands `typeof window` so `renderToString` never hits the second `return` that has the html and that html is never built.

Comment: If you say that the `useEffect` hook *doesn't* run on the server, then `isClient` is `false` and  `renderToString` will render the `null` value, not the fragment with the h1 and children. The initial html is empty. And that's why it works, as the empty html can be hydrated with React without the warning, before the effect runs and React will render the fragment.

Comment: The component is converted from a function to `React.createElement` using what's in the `return` method. In the first, `createElement` is passed the html from the `return` method because React isn't running yet. In the second, it sees `typeof window`, understands that, and passes `null` to `createElement`. It's all run through `renderToString` then React starts. In the first, React sees the html but sees `false` set in React and returns null, but that html is in the React tree now. In the second, react sees `null` so when it encounters that html, it's not in the React tree - hence the warning.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "*React sees the html but sees `false` set in React and returns null*". That's not how React works, and I doubt it is how Next works either. `isClient` is `false`, and the code after the `if` statement never runs, `React.createElement` is never called.

Comment: @Bergi I updated the response because I wanted to include some sample code and more explanation.

Comment: But "*Because of this hook, React is aware that this component can return either the html or null.*" is wrong. React is not some magical artificial intelligence that is "aware" of anything. It will just render a `SamplePageWithHook`, and it will return `null`. It might render it again after the effect ran, then it will return the fragment. The point is that if on the first render, it doesn't produce the same DOM as the server-generated html did, it'll emit that warning. The problem is that `SamplePageWithNull` does always (including the first render) return the fragment on the client.

Comment: I'm not using `getInitialProps` or `getServerSideProps`. I do use a custom `_app` and `_document`. I think I mixed up the terminology. According to NextJS docs, SSG without data is automatically used unlike SSR. I think I now understand NextJS is comparing the initial render in both client and server.

Answer (score -1):

First, if SEO is not important for your project try to implement your project with pure React however you can implement react in next.js so send your request in useEffect because useEffect just runs on the client-side so your page is not SSR.